# Create wall art / projection for actual walls

Tags: uv, export, camera, distort

I am trying to create wall art for optical illusions (e.g. person stands close to the edge of a canyon when in reality it's just painted on the floor) with Blender, but since I am a complete newbie I don't really know the best way to do this.

Currently I have the camera positioned at a spot where the actual camera in the room would be and a plane with extruded edges to create the walls and subdivided it.

[image: Sample of camera view with plane]

Now I am struggling to get the image onto the plane so the parts of the image ending up on the floor would be in perspective.

**Important:** I also need to export each side of the plane  (e.g. back wall, side wall, floor) separately so it can be printed out accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of found a way to achieve it, unsure if it is the optimal solution:

- Add a background image to the camera which is the image to be projected onto the walls
- Adjust the scene dimensions to the dimensions of the image
- Subdivide the plane, add a UV projection and project from view of the camera after positioning the plane so the image fits
- Add a material to the plane and use the image itself, so it renders onto the plane
- Add three additional cameras, each pointing at a wall / the floor and setting them to orthographic.

When exporting the rendered images from the three additional cameras, each of them should have the perspective view of the wall / floor.